# Where is the jsf.ajax.request function defined in Mojarra?

Tags: ajax, jsf, mojarra

The Mojarra repository is too huge to download everything and a quick

```
find -name *.js -exec grep -H "ajax\.request =" {} \;
```

on my local jboss install or the repository didn't bring up any file.

How does one find locations like that in a huge codebase most efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it via a google search on line 1454 at:

https://javaserverfaces.java.net/docs/2.0/jsdocs/symbols/src/_Users_edburns_Documents_Projects_JavaEE_workareas_mojarra-HEAD_jsf-api_src_main_resources_jsf.js.html